# Using Datatables's FixedHeader with jLayout

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

Are there anyone using Datatables FixedHeader with jLayout?

A table is placed in a div.

And the table's header is not properly placed after jLayout placing the div.

Is there any solution to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer myself.

Add a listener to the div to catch resize event.  Upon resize, add FixedHeader to relevant DataTables.

```
$('#somediv').resize(function(e) {

  new FixedHeader($('#sometable').dataTable());

});
```